# Issues with internet connection using bridge mode on Telstra Smart Modem Gen 2 & Asus RT-AC68U

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet-connection, modem

**Context**

My Telstra service worked well over wifi using the default setup (using the Smart Modem as the modem and router). However instead, I want to use it in bridge mode to take advantage of my Asus router's features.

**Setup**

I've used the following steps to try to enable bridge mode on the Telstra Smart Modem 2 (listing out since this isn't documented anywhere by Telstra or the manufacturer):

1. Disable wifi using the physical button on the rear panel
2. In the Telstra modem admin GUI at `192.168.0.1`, Go To Advanced -> Internet -> WAN Services -> Toggle 'bridge enabled' to off. Confirm and wait for the progress bar and for the modem to reboot. After reboot, the admin GUI is no longer accessible (as expected in bridge mode).
3. Connected Telstra modem's LAN port to Asus router's WAN port.
4. Setup the Asus RT-AC68U router's SSID and leaving other router settings out of the box. This uses Asuswrt-Merlin firmware, version 384.14_2.

Unfortunately there isn't a technical user manual available for the Telstra modem - the only manual is the very simplistic device setup guide.

**Issue**

After the above, the internet connection works well using LAN ports, and the wifi mostly works on iPhone, but with some issues. The primary issue is that Whatsapp cannot connect (says "Connecting..." with never-ending progress pinwheel) which means messages aren't received until I'm off the wifi network. Similarly, connections to Lifx and Apollo apps are patchy, however these are less important.

Any suggestions out there? I'm hopeful the above gives some clue to more experienced users on what settings I should look into tweaking.

Comment: Since *"the internet connection works well using LAN ports"* why are you still focusing on the *"bridge mode of the Telstra Smart Modem"*?  Seems like the issue is with the *"setup the Asus router's wifi settings"*, for which you provide zero details.

Comment: @sawdust Hmm, I didn’t go into detail on them since they’re completely out of the box. What details from the router would help to share?

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to achieve? Please provide a diagram on how you want to connect everything.

Comment: What were the WiFi settings on the Telstra Smart Modem?  What are the  WiFi settings on the Asus WiFi router?  Instead of just the button, try reconfiguring the Telstra to actually disable its WiFi, or use alternate settings (i.e. SSID, RF channel) that will not match with what you actually use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @sawdust's stellar guidance I queried the router rather than modem and found the fix.

There is a common issue that occurs where NAT acceleration on Asus routers disrupts Whatsapp connectivity [per this Whirlpool discussion](https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/3n4y4l83).

The following steps fixed the issue:

1. Login to the Asus router admin GUI at `http://192.168.1.1/`
2. Toggle off NAT acceleration: LAN -> Switch Control -> NAT acceleration -> Disable

Whatsapp now works reliably over wifi, and the Lifx app now connects reliably to lightbulbs too.